# Modulus division returns an integer?

Tags: php

Does modulus division only return integers? I need a float return. See the following:

```
var_dump(12 % 10); // returns 2, as expected
var_dump(11.5 % 10); // returns 1 instead of 1.5?
```

Comment: See the alternative function suggested by @tom_yes_tom

Comment: @mauris: your addition is not correct I suppose. I'm sure the last phrase changes the initial question

Comment: @zerkms incorrect in what sense? I tried improving the quality of the post. There is no need for "PHP" to be in the title as the post is tagged as such.

Comment: @mauris: I'm about "workaround" part

Comment: @zerkms oh c'mon! that one line?!

Comment: @mauris: yes. The OP's question was `Does modulus division only return integers?`

Comment: quoting from the OP "I need a float return"... ah nevermind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  the `%` operator returns an integer.

If you want a floating point result, use the [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function instead.

Answer (score 4):

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the
>   decimal part) before processing.

11.5 becomes 11.

`11 % 10 = 1 remainder **1**`

Your solution: [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php), as tom_yes_tom suggests.

Comment: This doesn't explain **why** it is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> "Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the
>   decimal part) before processing."

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any workaround for this?

mathematics...

`11.5 - floor(11.5 / 10) * 10 == 1.5`